# Add multiple rules exceptions with AND operator instead of OR

Tags: exchange-2007, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

In my outlook 2007 application on windows 7 I have created a rule to work with the incomming emails.
The rule needs to do the following:

- All incoming emails needs to be checked
- It needs to be printed
- Except if it comes from `test@example.com` **AND** body text contains 'ORDER'

When I try to accomplish this if give the OR operator between the 2 conditions. How can I change this so that the exceptions are both needed ( AND operator ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about to create two rules:

1. The rule that has 'from test@example.com' AND 'body contains ORDER' conditions and 'stop processing more rules' single action.
2. No conditions, just 'print' action.

If you need other rules and this way is not acceptable, you can modify the first rule to, say, 'assign a category' to emails instead of 'stop processing more rules'. Second rule will check all emails 'except if assigned to category'.

Comment: ok I didn't see the option to stop processing other rules. Thanks mate!